# UISegmentedControl does not keep its frame origin after viewDidLayoutSubviews

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisegmentedcontrol

I'm getting weird behavior when using viewDidLayoutSubviews to arrange controls for a view controller.  I put multiple controls (labels, text boxes, date pickers and segmented controls) on a view controller in interface builder.  In viewDidLoad, I hide some of these controls, and the rest need to be rearranged (scooted up) so that there are no gaps where the hidden controls are.

When the view loads, viewDidLayoutSubviews fires and the controls are all arranged as desired.  But then if you tap on the segmented control it "loses" its frame origin and reverts back to its original location from IB.  What is firing that would make the segmented control lose its frame origin?

Then if you edit a text field, viewDidLayoutSubviews fires again and the segmented control moves back to the desired location.  This doesn't seem appropriate--I am not performing any setFrame or other action that would require this.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // arbitrarily hide two of the controls
    _textField2.hidden = YES;
    _textField4.hidden = YES;
}

- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    // move the controls up in the view if any preceding controls are hidden
    float currentYPosition = _textField1.frame.origin.y;

    NSArray *arrayControls = @[_textField1, _textField2, _segmentedControl1, _textField3, _textField4, _textField5];

    for (int i=0; i < arrayControls.count; i++) {
         // move the associated control...also capture the offset to the next label/control
        UIView <NSObject> *object = (UIView <NSObject> *)[arrayControls objectAtIndex:i];
        float newYPosition = [self rearrangeFrame:object withCurrentYPosition:currentYPosition];

        // update our reference to the current Y position
        currentYPosition = newYPosition;
    }
}

- (float)rearrangeFrame:(id)controlObject withCurrentYPosition:(float)topSpaceToSuperview {
    // input:  control on the view that needs to be rearranged
    // output:  the updated y coordinate for the next control

    float padding = 3.0f;
    if ([controlObject conformsToProtocol:@protocol(NSObject)]) {
        UIView <NSObject> *object = (UIView <NSObject> *) controlObject;
        if (object.hidden) {
            // return a box with a height of 0 if the control is hidden
            [object setFrame:CGRectMake(object.frame.origin.x, topSpaceToSuperview, object.frame.size.width, 0)];
            return topSpaceToSuperview;
        } else {
            // update the y position of the control's frame origin
            [object setFrame:CGRectMake(object.frame.origin.x, topSpaceToSuperview, object.frame.size.width, object.frame.size.height)];
            return topSpaceToSuperview + object.frame.size.height + padding;
        }
    } else {
        return topSpaceToSuperview;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably because auto layout is on (it's on by default). When moving views with auto layout, you have to change the constraints, not set frames. So to fix this problem. you either need to turn off auto layout or change your code to use constraints.

Comment: Okay got it.  So then, do I need to create all of my controls programmatically and then assign constraints?  This appears to work, but I was hoping to use IB to layout the controls and then simply move them.  That (adding constraints to an existing control) does not appear to work.

Comment: @ken-man, you can make IBOutlets to the constraints, and change the constant parameter, or remove and replace them if you need to. Usually, when I animate, I just change the constant value in an animation block.